# re.split - micropython - why is it not working?

Tags: python, micropython

im have re.split problem.

im try:

```
>>>
dms = "50°49.21544' N"
m = re.compile("[^\d\w]+")
m.split(dms)
['', '']
```

im want:
["50", "49", "21544", "N"]

Comment: Micropython's `ure` module seems to be quite limited - it may not support character ranges such as `\d` inside of character sets.  Perhaps `[^0-9NESW]+` would work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you almost have it, just use `m = re.compile("[^\w]+")` the \w includes alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

`import re
dms = "50°49.21544' N"
re.split(r"[°,.]",dms)`

out

`['50', '49', '21544', 'N']`